# Animate an element when Chrome is loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to make a progress bar for when the user exports an image file on my site. Similar to this example https://jsfiddle.net/rz8jm5hv/2/ . The problem I'm having is that in Chrome when an alert comes on screen it freezes everything in the DOM other than the alert box which I know is how Chrome alerts work but it also freezes animations when an image is loading.

For example, when I call:

```
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,[base64 data]"
```

Firefox will render animation in the background while the image is loading but Chrome freezes all animation until after the `img.onload` runs.

Can someone explain why this happens and if there is a way I can work around this issue in Chrome?